# Change structure of html with jQuery when responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i want is to change te structure of my HTML page when going under 640px.
this is the structure i have:

```
<div class="people_row">    
    <div class="single_person 0"></div>
    <div class="single_person 1"></div>
    <div class="single_person 2"></div>
    <div class="single_person 3"></div>
    <div class="single_person 4"></div>
    <div class="single_person 5"></div>
    <div class="info_block 0"></div>
    <div class="info_block 1"></div>
    <div class="info_block 2"></div>
    <div class="info_block 3"></div>
    <div class="info_block 4"></div>
    <div class="info_block 5"></div>
    <div class="single_person 6"></div>
    <div class="single_person 7"></div>
    <div class="single_person 8"></div>
    <div class="single_person 9"></div>
    <div class="single_person 10"></div>
    <div class="single_person 11"></div>
    <div class="info_block 6"></div>
    <div class="info_block 7"></div>
    <div class="info_block 8"></div>
    <div class="info_block 9"></div>
    <div class="info_block 10"></div>
    <div class="info_block 11"></div>
</div>
```

What i want is:

```
<div class="people_row">    
    <div class="single_person 0"></div>
    <div class="single_person 1"></div>
    <div class="single_person 2"></div>
    <div class="info_block 0"></div>
    <div class="info_block 1"></div>
    <div class="info_block 2"></div>
    <div class="single_person 3"></div>
    <div class="single_person 4"></div>
    <div class="single_person 5"></div>
    <div class="info_block 3"></div>
    <div class="info_block 4"></div>
    <div class="info_block 5"></div>
    <div class="single_person 6"></div>
    <div class="single_person 7"></div>
    <div class="single_person 8"></div>
    <div class="info_block 6"></div>
    <div class="info_block 7"></div>
    <div class="info_block 8"></div>
    <div class="single_person 9"></div>
    <div class="single_person 10"></div>
    <div class="single_person 11"></div>
    <div class="info_block 9"></div>
    <div class="info_block 10"></div>
    <div class="info_block 11"></div>
</div>
```

i don't want duplicate div's in my code and do a display block on that elements when dropping under 640px. I would like to do this with jQuery.

Thanks
Stein

Edit :
i tried this but there must be a better solution than this:

```
var infoblock0 = $(".info_block.0").html();
$(".info_block.0").remove();
$(".single_person.2").after("<div class='info_block 0'>"+infoblock0+"</div>");

var infoblock1 = $(".info_block.1").html();
$(".info_block.1").remove();
$(".single_person.2").after("<div class='info_block 1'>"+infoblock1+"</div>");

var infoblock2 = $(".info_block.2").html();
$(".info_block.2").remove();
$(".single_person.2").after("<div class='info_block 2'>"+infoblock2+"</div>");

var infoblock6 = $(".info_block.6").html();
$(".info_block.6").remove();
$(".single_person.8").after("<div class='info_block 6'>"+infoblock6+"</div>");

var infoblock7 = $(".info_block.7").html();
$(".info_block.7").remove();
$(".single_person.8").after("<div class='info_block 7'>"+infoblock7+"</div>");

var infoblock8 = $(".info_block.8").html();
$(".info_block.8").remove();
$(".single_person.8").after("<div class='info_block 8'>"+infoblock8+"</div>");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry that i didn't post what i tried, This works buts its ugly. i putted it up so maybe someone knew a better solution

Comment: Why don't you go for Bootstrap? You might want to use only responsive code here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=14324ec730d2c811deb4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you want is to reorder the elements when the window is resized, right?

You can try the following code...

```
$(function() {

var screenBig = $(window).width() >= 640;

$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 640 && screenBig) {
        resizeSmall();
        screenBig = false;
    } else if($(window).width() >= 640 && !screenBig) {
        resizeBig();
        screenBig = true;
    }
});

var resizeSmall = function() {
    var orig = $('.people_row');
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.0'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.1'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.2'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.0'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.1'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.2'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.3'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.4'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.5'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.3'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.4'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.5'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.6'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.7'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.8'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.6'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.7'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.8'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.9'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.10'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.11'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.9'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.10'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.11'));
}

var resizeBig = function() {
    var orig = $('.people_row');
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.0'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.1'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.2'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.3'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.4'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.5'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.6'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.7'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.8'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.9'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.10'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.single_person.11'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.0'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.1'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.2'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.3'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.4'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.5'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.6'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.7'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.8'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.9'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.10'));
    orig.append(orig.find('.info_block.11'));

}
});
```

I haven't tested it but you should get the point ;)

Basically, it adds a listener to the window resize event, and when CHANGES to more than 640px or less than 640px it runs the corresponding function.

That's why the `screenBig` variable is there, to avoid running the resize functions in each resize (i.e. resizing from 1000px to 900px does not need executing the function).

The functions just reorders your elements as you want.

Also, you can try a framework for responsive design, but if you just want simple things, this should work ^^

Comment: Thanks for your comment! but the orig is not defined. What do i must do?

Comment: Sorry I forgot. It is now :)